# services.yaml configuration - autowire without namespace

Tags: symfony, symfony4

How can I autowire my classes with the following folder-structure:

```
src
 -folder1
  --folder1.1
  --folder1.2
 -folder2
 -folder3
```

PSR-4 allows autoloading root directories in the `composer.json` like this (e.g.):
`"": "src/"`

In symfony to autowire all classes in the given folder you approach it in the `services.yaml`
Default-Configuration:

```
  App\:
    resource: 'src/*'
    exclude: 'src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Where `App\` becomes the default namespace (which I can't use as the default namespace).
I want to achieve the same thing in the `services.yaml` what I did in the `composer.json`.

Something like this:

```
  some.id:
    namespace: ''
    resource: 'src/*'
    exclude: 'src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Also I dont want to add 50-60 lines of namespace implementation like this:

```
Namespace1\:
   resource: ...
   exclude: ...
Namespace2\: ...
Namespace3\: ...
```

Comment: Short of modifying the base code I don't see any way to support your layout structure.  But just out of curiosity, what motivated you to create 60 different namespace prefixes?  Seems a bit excessive.

Comment: Wasn't me. Most likely Legacy-Stuff. Project grown over the years.

Comment: Maybe someone else can help but I suspect you just have to define your services the old fashion way.  Kind of surprised that autoloading even works.

Comment: You *could* use the PHP format to configure your services. That would allow you to traverse the directory first and create the resources dynamically. But you will need to be extra carefully about which directories you would rather want to exclude (especially thinking about this when new files or directories are created).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no way to get this folder-structure to work with autowiring without adding a global namespace (like `App\`), adding every namespace in `services.yaml` or modifying the base code.

What I did was adding the global namespace `App\` in the `src` folder.